# How do I fix boolean error in Rails 3.4 activeadmin on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I have the following form parsial that I'm using in activeadmin on in a rails project running on heroku. Locally I'm using sqlite and the form works great.

```
    <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @instagram_tag_search] do |f| %>

       <%= f.inputs do %>
            <%= f.input :name %>
            <%= f.input :active, :as => :boolean  %>
       <% end %>

       <%= f.buttons %>
    <% end %>
```

On heroku I get the following error

```
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `active' for #<InstagramTagSearch:0x000000068893b0>):
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:    
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:            <%= f.input :name %>
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:    <%= f.inputs do %>
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <% end %>
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:            <%= f.input :active, :as => :boolean  %>
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: 
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:    <%= f.buttons %>
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/admin/instagram_tag_searches/_form.html.erb:5:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_admin_instagram_tag_searches__form_html_erb___2113834955800283278_53730580'
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/admin/instagram_tag_searches/_form.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_admin_instagram_tag_searches__form_html_erb___2113834955800283278_53730580'
2012-09-03T16:01:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/admin/instagram_tag_searches/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_admin_instagram_tag_searches__form_html_erb___2113834955800283278_53730580'
```

It seems to me there is a difference in the way postgreSQL and sqlite handle the boolean / checkbox. Locally the value I am storing is a 1 or 0. I'm wondering what the simple fix is for this.

Comment: I did run all migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you have run all the migrations on heroku.  They normally aren't run as part of a deploy/push.

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I did check this ... all migrations have been run

Comment: heroku run console; InstagramTagSearch.column_names.sort; Is active in the list?  Can you set it manually on an instance of InstagramTagSearch?

Comment: There must have been an issue with heroku instance I run this on because 5 min later everything worked fine and I didn't do anything to fix it.